# rabbit mq worker on restart gets loads of events

Tags: python, rabbitmq, rabbitmq-exchange

I followed the following link to consumer connection 
http://pika.readthedocs.org/en/latest/examples/asynchronous_consumer_example.html

I observe a peculiar behaviour that whenever i close by worker and again restart it, its flooded with events. Not sure why. These events are basically events which were passed to it previously.

What i understand is that , these events are still retained in the exchange and when i start my worker, it connects to the exchange and gets all the events again.
btw i am using fanout exchange type

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that i was not sending an acknowlegement back once i recieve event. This resulted in the exchange not clearing the job that it recieved and resulted it it being loaded again on reconnect